# How to use OAuth 2 for authentication in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, oauth-2.0

> I am very confused about how to authenticate a user with OAuth 2. But I am comfortable when using JWT. Please can you make me understand with an example using OAuth 2?
>
> 1. When user gets registered.
> 2. User Login.

I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: your question is too broad.

Comment: you can check the git link https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2 or use npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to first get familiar with [OAuth2 workflow](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) and then you could use something like [this](https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2).